# How to complete the P.T. Demo on PS4?

Tags: ps4, silent-hill-series, pt

I have played the P.T. (Playable Teaser AKA Silent Hill) Demo a few times but always get stuck at the very end and seem to be in a constant loop.

I know there is some sort of sequence that needs to be performed to be able to stop the looping corridors and to reveal the end video but no matter how many different sequences I try it never seems to work.

**I've tried many of the walkthroughs online but none seem to do the trick.**

**Has anyone actually completed it?** and what sequence did you use?

Comment: Pewdiepie did a video on this a day or two ago.  I would watch the  video to see if it helps.

Comment: @Caleb I'd prefer not to watch anything with Pewdiepie in it.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously this is later down the road than you may have wanted.  I am sure there are more detailed walkthroughs out there today AND I certainly hope you haven't uninstalled the game.  BUT... There are many ways to complete the game, but most ways are not entirely completing it.  I followed the FAQ below and got every detail of the game and finished with correct ending / teaser.  There are MANY ways to complete this demo  This is by far the most terrifying game I have ever played, and its so beautiful.  I hope this works for you!

[And yes, the game was technically cancelled... sad...]

[IGN P.T. Walkthrough](http://www.ign.com/wikis/silent-hills/P.T._Demo_Walkthrough)

As a backup in case the link stops working in the near future, here are the proper steps (Summed Up) to complete P.T.:

Leave the starting area and make your FIRST pass through the hallway and down the staircase.

Head to the stairway door to see it is closed. Turn around and head back towards the door you came through.  The door on your left will begin to shake (This is the bathroom door). Once at the starting place, turn around and head back to the stairway to find it open.  Head down the stairs to complete your SECOND pass.

Head for the stairway again.  Before you reach the open doorway the door will slam shut. Approach and essentially hit the door until your controller shakes.  You will head a door creak behind you. Approach the bathroom door to see bugs escaping. You will hear a Baby crying in the bathroom. Go to the crack of the bathroom door and peer in using (R3). A "woman-like" creature will show up and slam the door shut.  Head to the stairway to finish the THIRD pass.

Head for the stairway. Once you see the hulking ghoul around the corner continue to approach him until the light flickers, and turns off.  Head to the stairway to finish the FOURTH pass.

Head for the stairway.  This time the bathroom door will be entirely open.  Head inside to find a flashlight on the floor.  Zoom in (R3) to pick it up.  The door will slam shut.  Head to the sink and view "it".  Look above the sink (at the reflection of yourself) to hear the door creak open.  Head into the hallway and proceed to the stairway to end loop FIVE.

Head for the stairway and proceed down the stairwell to complete loop SIX.

Head for the stairway and listen for the radio (you may need to wait a moment to hear the specific dialogue) to say "Look Behind You".  Do it.  BOO!  Loop SEVEN complete.

Note: Before you begin this loop, look around the room you wake up in.  Use your flashlight to find the talking box (at least that's what I believe it is).  This is also a good loop to find picture fragments on. Location Below.

Head for the stairway.  You will see a photo next to the radio in the hallway with a message "Gouge it out!" on it. Zoom (R3) in on the Blue X and hit the (X) button.  This will burn out one eye and the door will open.  Head down the stairs, reading "I can hear them calling to me from" on the way, to complete Loop EIGHT.

Head for the stairway noticing everything is red now.  Step under the bloody fridge and head down the stairway to complete the NINTH Loop.

Head for the Phone in this pass to see the word "HELLO" written on the wall. Head to the foyer where you see "calling to me from" again. The letter "L" should appear. Make three more trips from "HELLO" to the foyer where "L" had appeared to spell out "HELL".  Head down the stairs to complete Loop TEN.

Enter the hallway yet again where the fridge has been replaced with a single swinging red light.  Enter the red hallways and find a picture frame that had fallen off the wall with a hole behind it.  Use Zoom (R3) to peer through the hole.  Hold (R3) while listening to the audio.  Once you are forced out of the peer hole, continue down the hallway and down the stairs to complete Loop ELEVEN.

The rest of the demo is straight forward.  It will take control of your screen, play some subliminal messages and then cut out to the "Silent Hills" teaser.  This may be a bit choppy, I will edit it to clean it up tomorrow.  I really hope this helps someone out because this game is worth every sketchy second of playing.  Again, its a real shame that it was cancelled.

Picture Fragment Locations:

1. On the floor beneath the clock, among the discarded cans and bottles.
2. On the vase which hold the potted plant, to the right of the clock.
3. Beneath the window near the phone, near the teddy bear on the floor.
4. Lodged in the ceiling beam between the foyer and the bathroom
5. On the stairway leading down to the Loop door.
6. In the [adjust brightness] Options menu (press R3 while in the menu to collect this piece)

Final Puzzle Notes [can be completed on the last Loop] (via [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/silent-hills/P.T._Demo_Walkthrough)):

1. Everything must be attempted after the clock strikes midnight.
2. Players should have a microphone or headset plugged into their Dualshock 4 controller.
3. In order for the phone to ring, you must hear a baby laugh 3 times.
4. Walking exactly ten paces in any direction will trigger a laugh.
5. After the second laugh, FREEZE. Do not move, do not adjust the camera - after a few seconds your controller will begin to vibrate. Remain motionless until the vibrations cease entirely, and the third laugh will trigger.
6. The phone will begin to ring after all three laughs.

Comment: @Mumford451 Could you edit your question to include one or more possible methods of completion? AS frank said said this is helpful if the link goes away, but it also makes the information a lot easier to find if it's just in your answer rather than on another page (where the user will need to search through the page for it themselves).

Comment: @Wipqozn - Absolutely!  Sorry, still a bit new to SE.  I will edit it right away, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: Wow, great improvement! Thanks for adding all this information to your  answer!

Comment: Absolutely @Wipqozn thanks for giving me the heads up about the link :)

Answer (score 0):

Saying his name works ALWAYS for me, tried 3 times already. First do the 10 steps, the baby will laugh. Then when she starts crying/breathing wait until she shuts up and while the radio static is still playing say in your ps4 mic Jerath. Always works. Then just wait until the controller starts vibrating and dont move, not even a bit for the thirth laugh. The phone will ring and thats it.